# Issue with mocks using jest and supertest in strapi

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, strapi, ts-jest

I'm currently facing difficulties with writing mocks for my API tests. I have tried various approaches, but I haven't been able to make even the simplest mocks work, despite them working in another environment where I directly import the code instead of using supertest to test API endpoints.

The original problem arose when I attempted to mock the Stripe module. However, while investigating the issue and testing different mock setups, I realized that even the simplest mocks don't work with supertest.

Here's an example of a basic mock that I'm trying to make work, but without success:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/__mocks__/*",
    "node_modules",
    "\\.tmp",
    "\\.cache",
    "<rootDir>/dist/*",
    "<rootDir>.*/public",
  ],
  roots: ["<rootDir>/__test__"],
  globalSetup: "<rootDir>/__test__/helpers/globalSetup.js",
  globalTeardown: "<rootDir>/__test__/helpers/globalTeardown.js",
};
```

```
// my.test.js
const request = require("supertest");
const utils = require("../../src/lib/utils");
jest.mock("../../src/lib/utils", () => {
  return {
    getEvent: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("I am the getEvent mock"),
  };
});

describe("Subscription API", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  describe("POST /subscriptions/webhook", () => {
    it("should handle customer.subscription.created event", async () => {
      const res = await request(strapi.server.httpServer)
        .post(`/api/subscriptions/webhook`)
        .set("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
        .send({ payload: "foo" });

      const customer: Customer = await strapi
        .query("api::customer.customer")
        .findOne({ idp_id: customerMock.metadata.idp_id });
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```

The strapi controller:

```
import { getEvent } from "../../../lib/utils";
export default factories.createCoreController(
  "api::subscription.subscription",
  ({ strapi }) => ({
    async webhook(ctx) {
      const a = getEvent();
      console.log(a);
    },
  })
);
```

And the utils file:

```
export const getEvent = () => {
  console.log("I am the getEvent original");
};
```

What am I missing? Where could the issue be? I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance in resolving this problem!

I tried manual mocks, mocking the whole module, mocking the function, mockReturnValue, mockImplementation, every different suggestion on stackoverflow, etc.